# Default Error page in Jboss EAP to be disabled or modified

Tags: jboss-eap-6

How to find the location of default error page in **Jboss EAP 6.2**

Below is the default Error message being displayed

```
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /we

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /we

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1 

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
```

We do not want to display the app server error page in case some random URL is keyed in

Kindly suggest us on this

Answer (score 0):

This error page is part of the the default root web application.

To disable it change the configuration of the default virtual-server `enable-welcome-root` property from `true` to `false`.

For example in `standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" proxy-name="localhost" proxy-port="80"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
```

Comment: sorry, i took the example fragment from my instance of jboss-eap-6.4. 
I have now amended it to use a jboss-eap-6.2 example.